# Python Flask error: /lxml/objectify.so: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_GetName

Tags: python, linux, flask, lxml, lxml.objectify

I am getting undefined symbol error when attempting to run code that utilizes lxml via my flask application.  The code runs without issue at the terminal, but errors out when processed through the web app:

**/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/objectify.so: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_GetName**

Running Python 2.7.9 on a linux server.  Any thoughts on how to get around this?  I've tried re-installing other versions of lxml (via pip) without success.

Comment: Sounds a lot like lxml is not installed properly. Try reinstalling it.

Comment: I've tried re-installing several times with different versions even....no luck.  As I said, it runs properly via terminal session, so I'm confused why it errors out in web app.